# How to get tab-initiated lines using Findstr /B [TAB] in Bat/CMD

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, findstr

There is an option that works in **[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184263)**:
Like **[@jimmij](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/80886/jimmij)** answer command: **`grep -B2 '^\t' file`**.

But is there an option using only **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** with the **`Findstr`** command?

Already tried..

```
Findstr /bl [0x09] "File.txt"
Findstr /b "[<0x09>]" "File.txt"

Findstr /bl "[\<0x09\>]" "File.txt"
Findstr /bl [\^<0x09\^>] "File.txt"

Findstr /b "[<0x09>]" "File.txt"
Findstr /b "[^<0x09^>]" "File.txt"

call findstr /b [^<0x09^>] "File.txt

cmd /u /c "Findstr /b "[<0x09>]" "File.txt""
cmd /u /s /c "Findstr /b "[^<0x09^>]" "File.txt""
cmd /u /s /c "call findstr /b [^<0x09^>] "File.txt""

%__AppDir__%Findstr /b "TAB" "file.txt"
%__AppDir__%Findstr /bl "TAB" "file.txt"
```

I can use a for loop and have / use the tab as a delimiter `if "%a"=="" (...`, or also I can use Unix/Win/Cygwin as well, but I am looking for an option that returns/gets straight to the beginning of the line only those that contain TAB using only what comes with Windows.

Comment: your last example is close. `TAB` is a standard delimiter though, so `findstr` uses it as delimiter, not as literal char. To change that, use the `/c` switch: `%__AppDir__%Findstr /bc:"<kbd>TAB</kbd>" "file.txt"` (sorry, no proper formatting in comments...)

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for comment, not work  with `b/c:"TAB"` or  `/bc:"%TAB%"`,

Comment: It has to be a literal tabulator (to be entered in Notepad (or whatever editor you use)). Also works with `%TAB%`, if `%TAB%` contains a literal tabulator. It won't work directly on the command line (because you are not able to enter `TAB` in a command line)

Comment: @Stephan Yes, i ve try by using var/literal, /b/c, but still not work, this is in bat/cmd file...

Comment: it works fine for me. Are you sure, it's a TAB, not spaces or a space followed by a TAB?

Comment: @Stephan Yep, sure, in notepad++ is some like "`--->`" tab var came from: **`for /f delims^=^  %%t in ('%__AppDir__%robocopy.exe /L .\. .\. /njh /njs')do set "_tab=%%t"`**

Comment: I meant within `file.txt`. Your `_TAB` generation is fine (works for me), so the fault has to be in `file.txt`. Either there are no TABs at the beginning of the line or maybe it's an encoding problem. Again: it works for me (with a plain ASCII encoded `file.txt`)

Comment: @Stephan The name and full path to file.txt is `%~f0`. I’m using the bat itself for test, and I can see tab in notepad encode UTF-8

Comment: @Stephan I have a backspace character after tab... <tab><backspace>

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very nice solution so hopefully someone finds an easier way. Using `findstr /G` pulls the search strings from a file, combine with `/B` flag makes the string match on beginning of line:

```
findstr /b /g:\Temp\yourpattern.txt File.txt
```

The file of search strings: `\Temp\yourpattern.txt` should be edited with a good text editor to contain a TAB character only.

Comment: Thanks, is one option, but I'm to try to do this without create a extra/new file...